# Can I control the output image quality/size with Puppeteer export to PDF?

Tags: puppeteer

When using Puppeteer to print a page as PDF, Puppeteer may convert images in that page to a different format.

For example, printing a [JPEG image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6WPB.jpg) will result in a PDF with (roughly) the same size as the image. That means Puppeteer is using the same exact JPEG image in the generated PDF. Same happens with other formats like PNG and SVG (the output size matches the size of the original images).

However, printing a WebP image will result in a PDF with a much bigger size (10x more that expected). This seems to be because Puppeteer is converting the WebP image into a JPEG/PNG image before generating the PDF.

I am guessing this is because WebP is not supported (maybe not even by the PDF standard and that may be the reason Puppeteer converts the WebP image in the first place).

Is there a way to control this image conversion? In particular, is it possible to set the target format (ideally JPEG) and quality (ideally < 100) to try to maintain the output size of the PDF in the same range as the input WebP image size?

Comment: You mean puppeteer is retaining the WEBP format?, since if it converted to jpeg it would be of less size.

Comment: @RinkeshP WebP format can perform lossy compression better than JPEG in many cases. WebP input image is of size X and, when exported to PDF with Puppeteer, the size of the PDF is 10X, so it is definitely not leaving the original image as-is. ^^

Comment: Ah. Some googling does show limitations of PDF not supporting webp.

Comment: @KJ So some JPEGs could also suffer from the same decompression with Puppeteer? Do you know which images could suffer from it or how to prevent it?

Comment: @Peque This is tedious but extracting the html and downloading all images, converting all images to specific format, then manually replacing the images in html with the converted images and finally generating the pdf should work.

Comment: @RinkeshP Yeah, I guess `sharp` could be used to convert to JPEG. As you say, it would be tedious. Specially since we are not talking about `<img>` tags only, but also CSS `background-image` properties... Not even sure how to deal with that.

Comment: @Peque I am guessing it would work fine, since css only takes effect in the browser. So theoretically it should work if you replace all image urls with the converted ones. The html content would be same except the images would now be loaded from local storage. Can't guarantee  how much the images would differ visually though.

Comment: Thanks @RinkeshP, I may try that. I need to understand how to ensure Puppeteer does not convert JPEGs to bitmaps though, since playing around a bit more it seems that it may sometimes decompress JPEG as well (in which case, converting to JPEG and replacing could end up with the same results). Maybe it is depending on the file size? On the image resolution? On other factor? :shrug:

Comment: @KJ Would you mind elaborating a bit more? (perhaps in an answer instead of a comment). I'd be happy to accept if you are able to indicate how to avoid JPEG inflation/deflation. In example: what do you mean with "if jpeg is trad"? Is there a way I could indicate, when exporting an image as JPEG, the type or options to make sure that the saved file will be used as-is when converting to PDF? (I am guessing it is not a try-your-luck thing).

Comment: @KJ Sorry, I think I didn't explain myself well. What I mean is: could I use an image editor to save a JPEG with specific format/options so that it is guaranteed that, when saving as PDF, it wont be inflated/deflated? When I say image editor I don't care if it is a command-line conversion tool or anything really that lets me create a JPEG image as long as it is compatible with PDF export and hence I can make sure the output PDF will contain the original image untouched.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you to see at two levels what happens to images when saved as pdf, now understand this is a basic demo thus not real world but just by explanation of considerations.

[image]

Upper left we have 5x5 pixels so screen rendering uses a blurring to not show images as "sharp" but upper right a pdf viewer tries to maintain vector sharpness.

so what about different formats, GIF TIF and PNG (middle line) are lossless and behave in roughly similar fashion. All should maintain colour pixel fidelity in a PDF.

However, lower line, Jpeg is lousy at maintaining colour fidelity because it spreads the colours between adjoining pixels, which is "Perfect" for fuzzy text or photographs but not much good for PDF colours.

Ok moving on your focus is input to pdf so what do those look like when stored.

each may be written in many ways but let's focus on the most versatile PNG.

```
%PDF-1.0

1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj

2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>endobj

3 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 3.75 3.75]/Rotate 0/Resources<</XObject<</Img3 6 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>>endobj

5 0 obj<</Length 34>>
stream
q
3.75 0 0 3.75 0 0 cm
/Img3 Do
Q
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj<</Length 75/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 5/Height 5/BitsPerComponent 8/SMask 7 0 R/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB>>
stream
ÿ  ÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿ@@@ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ   
endstream
endobj

7 0 obj
<</Length 5/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 5/Height 5/BitsPerComponent 1/ColorSpace/DeviceGray>>
stream
ÿÿÿÿÿ
endstream
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000062 00000 n 
0000000114 00000 n 
0000000334 00000 n 
0000000472 00000 n 
0000000555 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 7/Info<</Producer(Me)>>/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
684
%%EOF
```

Again, for illustration this is a non-typical stream as it shows the bitmap uncompressed but note the main image is defined by

```
6 0 obj<</Length 75/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 5/Height 5/BitsPerComponent 8/SMask 7 0 R/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB>>
```

So of interest it is 5 pixels wide by 5 pixels high NO hint of how many inches it's just 8 bits R, 8bits G, 8 bits B (again its only 3 colours) the Alpha is in a separate image (image Smask 7) so 3x5x5=75 is the uncompressed storage now we can compress many ways such as "Flate" (similar to say used in a zip file)
that will convert the stream from lots of `ÿ`s into a more compacted form.

Again, there are many encodings so if we wish to keep the pdf as text for editing in a text editor first

```
  /Length 72
  /Filter [ /ASCIIHexDecode /FlateDecode ]
>>
stream
789cfbcfc0f0ffff7f8605601244a002b0888383038c892a091582e86500009c
663a28>
endstream
```

Well that was not much compression down from 75 to 72 !
let's use something better by not using plain text.

```
6 0 obj
<</Length 36/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 5/Height 5/BitsPerComponent 8/SMask 7 0 R/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
xœû¯ ðÿÿ…`D °ˆƒƒŒ‰*©€P¤    ÞF;è
endstream
```

Ok much better we halved the storage from 72 down to 36 good its small compact and well formed.

So, what about keeping the jpeg structure ahhhh! that when maintaining its lousy nature needs 730

```
<</Filter/DCTDecode/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 5/Height 5/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Length 730>>
stream
ÿØÿà JFIF  ` `  ÿÛ C 
  








ÿÛ C        


ÿÀ   " ÿÄ               

ÿÄ µ   } !1AQa "q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ            

ÿÄ µ   w !1AQ aq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ   ? ëÿ j¯Ú[Á_ >|×õ¯„šgŽ¡ñ–™ý¥mg¨.˜ƒJ
§é€Æ„é®¬
´`©þ¬ ãŒ¢Šõiæ¸ì,ëáèUq„*ÖŒRÑ%³I}Ëüõ<ìFŽ*£¯QËšVnÓšWi_E$—ÉÿÙ
endstream
endobj
```

So this test piece is not real world but may serve to help make decisions over best storage means for different inputs.

My preference is use PNG where possible for charts and document text and use Jpeg only when essential for photos or fuzzy OCR.

taking your offered sample jpeg is necessary but even set quality to high with size reduction from maximal can suffer collateral damage.

However, it's not very noticeable except you zoom in closer than blobby anyway here 4 X zoom

**Source** 58-59 KB

[image]

**Slightly reduced** 50-51 KB

[image]